# Python: are there ways to detect missing () in method call?

Tags: python

I want to call a method `f()`, but accidentally I just say `f`. Python3 mistakes this for a meaningless evaluation of a nonexisting variable, and therefore skips over my intended method call without any notice. Is there a way to override this default behavior and to get an error message? Either by forbidding dual use of an identifier as a method and as a variable, or by forbidding a meaningless statement consisting just of an identifier?

Comment: `f` refers to the function without calling it, not the "meaningless evaluation of a nonexisting variable". That's why you don't get a `SyntaxError`. Python doesn't differentiate between function names and variable names - they are simply keys in the `globals()` dictionary.

Comment: *"forbidding dual use of an identifier as a method and as a variable"* -- in python, method *is* a variable

Comment: @Joachim, you're not quite right about what's happening (read @Volatility), but I understand why you want to warn against this. It's  an easy enough typo if you're used to writing Ruby.

Comment: @Colonel Panic: you guessed right: I am coming from Ruby. I won't say more, this is not the place to rant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's valid syntax, so Python won't complain.  You may want to consider some other tools, like pylint.  Pylint would've reported:

```
W:  4,0: Statement seems to have no effect
```

If you simply did:

```
f
```

instead of:

```
f()
```

The only catch is the pylint can complain an awful lot out of the box.  Make sure to create a config that is tolerant of your style.

Answer (score 3):

```
In [1]: def f():
   ...:     print("This is some random function")
   ...:     return

In [2]: a = f

In [3]: a()
This is some random function

In [4]: somedict = {"call_something": f, "call_another": a}

In [5]: somedict["call_something"]()
This is some random function

In [6]: f
Out[6]: <function __main__.f>
```

Using a function without calling it is completely valid syntax, and has various uses as I've just shown. It's not `a meaningless evaluation of a nonexisting variable`, because functions *are* variables essentially.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations. Still: a statement consisting just of the function name `f` _is_ meaningless, it is almost certainly an error, and I would appreciate ways to have it automatically detected.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to make sure your code does what it is supposed to is to write [unit tests](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/unittest.html). This type of bug cannot slip by if you have good test coverage.

Passing references to functions/methods is quite common (and useful) in Python, so it's not something you should want to disable.

Answer (score 0):

Alas, no. Python doesn't have any strict warning modes (cf. Perl and Ruby). Besides, such lines are valid statements, so it wouldn't be fair to warn against them.

You could write your own code checker to find lines like these though. Search for lines that are a single word without any punctuation, and that are a Python identifier (not a keyword such as `break`)